# Apple Music Like searchbarcontroller iOS swift

Tags: ios, animation, uisearchbar, apple-music

[image: Image shows the exact design]

I need to create a page which is similar to apple searchbarcontroller and it should include all the animations like apple. Please suggest me some thing now my application is working with some basic functions.

Comment: I think this [raywenderlich.com article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) might be helpful.

Comment: @Kyle I am looking for volume change slider, while I change volume from app slider the voule is decreasing but I cannot update the slider in app when I decrease or increase the volume from the device